# Mongoose: Difference between querying "value" or /value/i

Tags: mongoose

I am reading through Mongoose documentation to get into it.

I noticed something in its documentation but cant find further information about.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

the example talks about searching all documents by specific value (using "John")
and then talks about searching all documents LIKE by using (/John/i).

I found no further mention to this detail, so whats the real, practical implications of this? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case we search all documents with field `name` equal 'john'

```
await MyModel.find({ name: 'john' }).exec();
```

When we need to find documents that's `name` field contains sub-string 'john'  we can use regular expression `/john/` so we will find documents with `name` 'john', 'johnny', 'big john'.

The `i` modifier turn on case insensitivity, so `name` 'Johnson' and 'Johnathan' will be found as well

```
await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }).exec();
```